# How to keep track of users who have logged off so that they do not appear in the Online Now page?

Tags: php, mysql, database

On one of my sites I must keep track of users that are online.

There is a "login activity" table that keeps track of every user's login, so there are multiple rows per user in that table, one for each time a user has logged in (and whether they actually logged themselves out in that session).  This table was previously used to keep track of online users but wasn't very accurate because the script was considering any user that logged in in the last 10 minutes as being online unless they specifically logged off, at which point the row that was inserted during that login session has its "logged in" column set to "no".  The problem with this solution is that active users who had logged in over 10 minutes ago were not appearing "online".

To improve upon this, I've now added a "last activity" column to the main user table to keep track of the time of each user's last pageview and I'm calculating the "online now" as simply any user whose last activity was no more than 10 minutes ago.

However, how do I keep users who had activity in the last 10 minutes *but who have logged off* from appearing in the "online now" page?  Do I need to create a new table with one row per user just to keep track of when a user logged in and whether they logged themselves off?  Can I somehow use the existing "login activity" table even though it has multiple rows per user and query its most recent row to see if the user logged themselves off (but then how would I check the user's most recent "login activity" row as one of the criteria in a large join query?)?  Is there a simpler way?

Comment: js approach works better than db one, try [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047235/is-there-a-common-practice-to-track-the-user-session-across-browser-window). and if you don't need to be accurate in seconds, just drop 10 minutes to 1

Comment: [phpBB](http://www.phpbb.com) does what you want. It shows the number of logged in users and who they are. It even shows users looking at a particular page. In your position I would download their code and see how they've done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($member['lastactivity'] > (time()-600)){
                //user online code here...
            }else{
                //user offline code here
                }
```

i have a site of my own and use this code to check activity within the last 10mins, in my case, i use it to echo online/offline images next to users in the user browse page

Comment: What I'm trying to do is a bit different, I need to show OTHER users who is online, so I need to be able to exclude the users who have had activity in the last 10 minutes but who have also manually logged off.  Any ideas?

Comment: you could add a mysql update query in your logout function to set the users lastactivity back 10 mins `mysql_query("UPDATE users SET lastactivity = '".time()-600."'
WHERE id = 'usersid'");`

Comment: Thanks, that's actually really clever.  Are there any down-sides to doing it that way?  Is there a better way overall?

Answer (score 0):

One solution to keep track of how many and what user are currently online is by having a table(id/userId/lastModified) that holds the users who have logged in and as users log in and log out, populate and delete this table. It is possible that a user logged in, but either closed the browser and the log out never executed, one solution is to have an AJAX request sent to the server every x minutes reporting the user as online. If the lastModified field is greater than x minutes you can assume this user is not currently online.